# How to change the neural network model to improve the accuracy of mAP without learning from 0, but retraining already trained model

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection

how you can change the Faster R-CNN Resnet 101 or Faster R-CNN Inception Resnet V2 model to improve the accuracy of mAP detection without learning the model with 0, but retraining already trained model

Accuracy mAP needs to be improved though by a small amount.

maybe there are some approaches, even the name of these approaches

Comment: What do you want to change? If you keep the architecture but change only some hyperparameters you can load the old weights...

Comment: @dcolazin I would like to change the architecture if it is certainly possible without training with 0

Comment: If you give names to the layers in TF, and the names/sizes correspond to an older model, you can load specific layers with something like `model.load_weights('...',by_name=True)`, also if the complexive structure is different: for example, you can load all but the last weights trained on the 1000 imagenet classification and have a smaller last FC layer for other purposes